# Tag merge request - "Gmod" and "Garrys mod"

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, tag-merging

[gmod](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmod) and [garrys-mod](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garrys-mod) is the same game, it's just different ways of referencing it. They should be merged.